# Re-shaping data for plotting a network

Tags: r, ggally, ggnetwork

I have a data set that I would like to re-shape for plotting as a network ([following the work done here](http://www.et.bs.ehu.es/cran/web/packages/ggCompNet/vignettes/examples-from-paper.html)). The initial data frame looks like this:

```
authors <- c('Author A', 'Author B', 'Author C', 
             'Author A', 'Author D', 'Author C')
affiliation <- c('University 1', 'University 2', 'University 1', 
                 'University 1', 'Institute 3', 'University 1')
manuscript <- c('Manuscript A', 'Manuscript A', 'Manuscript A', 
                'Manuscript B', 'Manuscript B', 'Manuscript B')
df <- data.frame(authors, affiliation, manuscript)
```

I would like to re-shape this so that for each manuscript, I can get every combination of authors with the primary author's affiliation (I hope the way I am asking this question makes sense). This would result in the following data frame:

```
df_network <- data.frame('primary_author'= c('Author A', 'Author A', 
                                             'Author B', 'Author B', 
                                             'Author C', 'Author C', 
                                             'Author A','Author A', 
                                             'Author D', 'Author D', 
                                             'Author C', 'Author C'),
                         'connection'= c('Author B', 'Author C', 
                                         'Author A', 'Author C', 
                                         'Author A', 'Author B', 
                                         'Author D', 'Author C', 
                                         'Author A', 'Author C', 
                                         'Author A', 'Author D'),
                         'primary_affiliation' = c('University 1', 'University 1',
                                                   'University 2', 'University 2',
                                                   'University 1', 'University 1',
                                                   'University 1', 'University 1',
                                                   'Institute 3', 'Institute 3',
                                                   'University 1', 'University 1'),
                         'manuscript' = c('Manuscript A', 'Manuscript A',
                                          'Manuscript A', 'Manuscript A',
                                          'Manuscript A', 'Manuscript A',
                                          'Manuscript B', 'Manuscript B',
                                          'Manuscript B', 'Manuscript B',
                                          'Manuscript B', 'Manuscript B'))
```

Of course I can re-shape the data by hand but this is incredibly tedious, especially as the list gets very long. I have done this before (manually), and if I can get the data in the shape of `df_network` then the result is quite nice. Any tips or tricks anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  left_join(df, by = "manuscript") %>% 
  filter(!authors.x == authors.y) %>% 
  select(primary_author = authors.x, 
         connection = authors.y, 
         primary_affiliation = affiliation.x, 
         manuscript)
```

Output:

```
   primary_author connection primary_affiliation   manuscript
1        Author A   Author B        University 1 Manuscript A
2        Author A   Author C        University 1 Manuscript A
3        Author B   Author A        University 2 Manuscript A
4        Author B   Author C        University 2 Manuscript A
5        Author C   Author A        University 1 Manuscript A
6        Author C   Author B        University 1 Manuscript A
7        Author A   Author D        University 1 Manuscript B
8        Author A   Author C        University 1 Manuscript B
9        Author D   Author A         Institute 3 Manuscript B
10       Author D   Author C         Institute 3 Manuscript B
11       Author C   Author A        University 1 Manuscript B
12       Author C   Author D        University 1 Manuscript B
```

Comment: Wow! You are a wizard. It works perfectly. I don't know how to mark the question as answered, but this is it.

Comment: You're welcome @tlmoore! To accept the answer, you click on the tick sign left side of my answer - can also upvote by clicking on arrow above `0`.

Comment: Done! Don't have enough reputation to publicly upvote, but I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `data.table` for this task:

```
library('data.table')
df <- data.table(authors, affiliation, manuscript)
df <- merge(
  df, 
  df,
  by = 'manuscript', allow.cartesian = TRUE)[authors.x != authors.y, 
                                             .(primary_author = authors.x,
                                               connection = authors.y, 
                                               primary_affiliation = affiliation.x,
                                               manuscript)]
```